# Minimizing Ubuntu's size

Tags: storage

I have a VM with 40 GB of storage hosted in the cloud with Ubuntu and Wordpress for my blog.

Everything was fine until I upgraded to Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS: now my blog regularly crashes because of lack of disk space.

- Is there any way to track where new disk filling comes from?
- /var/lib is 29 GB. Can I downsize it? How?
- Any other tip welcome. I already removed old packages, limited  systemd journal logs

As asked:

```
...
28M     /var/lib/dpkg/info
30M     /var/lib/dpkg
40M     /var/lib/mecab/dic/ipadic
51M     /var/lib/mecab/dic/ipadic-utf8
91M     /var/lib/mecab
91M     /var/lib/mecab/dic
108M    /var/lib/apt
108M    /var/lib/apt/lists
155M    /var/lib/snapd/cache
156M    /var/lib/snapd
1.8G    /var/lib/mysql/wordpress
30G     /var/lib/mysql
31G     /var/lib
```

Comment: Do you know *where* in `/var/lib` the data is being used? If it's in `/var/lib/mysql`, then the work you need to do is in MySQL, not Ubuntu specifically. Can you update your question to include the output of `sudo du -h —max-depth=1 /var/lib | sort -h`? This will help narrow down where that space is being used.

Comment: The base size of Ubuntu server is 10Gb not more. All other data should be personal. `/var/lib` an Matigo suggests is database related. If it is `/var/www/` it is webserver related. If it is `/var/log/` check the log files ;-)  That long unformatted list is ... too long I removed all files with a size less than 1Mb. Your problem is with your databases: 30 Gb.

Comment: OK, the problem occured because of humongus logbin files enabled by default in mysql 8.
Either there was a circular flow because of a change in the database, or I've seen somewhere it could have occured because of a brute force attack on mysql logon
So far, I've deleted all binlog files and changed the configuration to disable binlogs by default
Imho, it is a very bad idea to suddenly change the default of a core option, especially if resulting circular updates caused by it are not a rare occurence.
Thank you Rinzwind for informing me a base size of Ubutu server is about 10 GB.

Answer (score 0):

By default, with the update to Mysql 8, binlogs were enabled and populated tens of GB within hours.
Myy solution was to delete the binlogs and deactivate a functionality that should never have been suddenly enable by default.
Thanks Rinzwind for pointing out to me that a bare ubuntu server install is about 10 GB.